# Mongodb: is it possible to do this in one query?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to Mongodb, Here is my document format:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5ee023790a0e502e3a9ce9e7"
    },
    "data": {
        "Quick": [
            ["1591745491", "4", "uwp"],
            ["1591745492", "4", "uwp"],
            ["1591745516", "12", "Word"],
            ["1591747346", "8", "uwp"]
        ]
        "Key": [
            ["1591747446", "Num"]
        ]
        "Search": [
            ["1591745491", "tty"],
            ["1591745492", "erp"],
            ["1591745516", "Word"],
            ["1591747346", "uwp"]
        ]

    },
    "devicecode": "MP1G5L9EMP1G5L9E@LENOVO"
}
```

What I want to do is:

- group by devicecode
- for each group, count how many times they used "Quick", "key" and "Search" (count how many line under the name)

Currently I am using a python program to get this done. but I believe that should be a way to get it done within Mongodb.

The output format should look like this:

```
devicecode: MP1G5L9EMP1G5L9E@LENOVO, Quick: 400, key: 350, Search: 660
...
```

Comment: How are you calculating Quick, Key and Search?

Comment: @Heena Tabassum,  under the Quick, Key and search, just count how many records, like this document, quick is 4, key is 1, and search is 4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use aggregation framework to compute the length of individual arrays in the `$set` stage and then in the `$group` stage group-by device while summing up the computed array length values from the previous stage. Finally, in the `$project` stage map `_id` to `devicecode` and deselect `_id`.

```
  db.getCollection("testcollection").aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      QuickLen: {
        $size: {
          $ifNull: [
            "$data.Quick",
            []
          ]
        }
      },
      KeyLen: {
        $size: {
          $ifNull: [
            "$data.Key",
            []
          ]
        }
      },
      SearchLen: {
        $size: {
          $ifNull: [
            "$data.Search",
            []
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$devicecode",
      Quick: {
        $sum: "$QuickLen"
      },
      key: {
        $sum: "$KeyLen"
      },
      Search: {
        $sum: "$SearchLen"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      devicecode: "$_id",
      Quick: 1,
      key: 1,
      Search: 1,
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: ran your script but got error:  2020-10-15T22:41:49.146-0600 E  QUERY    [js] Error: command failed: {
        "ok" : 0,
        "errmsg" : "The argument to $size must be an array, but was of type: missing",
        "code" : 17124,
        "codeName" : "Location17124"
} : aggregate failed :
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
doassert@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:18:14
_assertCommandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:583:17
assert.commandWorked@src/mongo/shell/assert.js:673:16
DB.prototype._runAggregate@src/mongo/shell/db.js:266:5

Comment: Here's the aggregation - https://mongoplayground.net/p/1mEO7b82zHM

Comment: Looks like there are some documents in your collection with missing array values.

Comment: yes, not all documents have all 3 values, some might have only 1 or 2, some documents the data field is empty.  Is it a way to fix this?

Comment: Ok. Try this. Just need to account for those nulls with $ifNull operator. - https://mongoplayground.net/p/85EwdmZSCVw